# How to answer the "How do you know" question at LinkedIn for a couple of scenarios?

Tags: linkedin

I am employed by the company Foo and work as a subcontractor for a consultant company Bar at the customer company Qux.

How should I answer "How do you know NameOfPerson?" at LinkedIn when I add:

1. a person who is employed at Qux.
2. a person who is employed by another consultant company.
3. a person who we (at Foo) hired as a consultant and worked with me for a while.
4. a teacher I had at the University who knows me but wasn´t really a ("real") friend.

In the list of answers I have:

- Colleague
- Classmate
- We’ve done business together
- Friend
- Other
- I don’t know NameOfPerson

In the colleague section, I only have the places where I have worked listed. As I am a consultant maybe there is a way to add the customers I´ve worked with?

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply select this one?

> We've done business together

It's a useful catch-all for cases like this.

Comment: The problem is that if you choose this option it forces you to choose one of the companies you listed as being employed at or enter a new employer on your linkedin profile (as of Feb 15, 2013 at least).

Comment: @Kmeixner - ah. That must be new behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I think that would fall under "We've Done business together"

Unless you wanted to add your consultant work to your profile and explain about it what you did for them. This would then allow you to use "colleage"

Comment: How would I add consultant work to my profile?

Comment: Id add it under organizations or experience as you would a job but it the job title just make it clear you where a consultant